# Is it possible to define Docker data volume on S3?

Tags: docker

Does EB provide the functionality to let docker use S3 as a logical volume?
From a scaling perspective, it would be quite nice to have File sharing across containers, if they all use the same S3 data to store files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use S3 as a logical volume.

I think that if you want to achieve that with S3 then your apps would have to make the corresponding S3 API calls to *put* objects in the corresponding bucket.

We use S3 for files/images and all the apps that need to access a bucket must have the corresponding credentials.

For persistent data to survive across containers restarts/rebuilds we use EBS and configure our containers with data volumes on it.